Will putting ATF instead of Dexron VI hurt my transmission?
I have a 2007 Pontiac G6 and it uses Dexron VI. I put ATF automatic transmission fluid in it instead. Is my car going to be okay? I just want to know if it mixes is it going to mess up my car?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Usually the bottle will say which specifications the fluid meets and what it is compatible with.  Which ATF did you use?
